# How do I get setInterval to run automatically without user input

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code for some of my coursework(I will admit). As you can see in the comments i have done the 'setinterval' with a button. But what I want is the 'setInterval' to be able to run automatically. What i mean by this is I do not want the user to have to click the button. Is there a way to do this and if so could you point me in the right direction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Task 3 Manual traffic lights</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1>

    <p >This is my Traffic Light script</p>

    <img id="change-light" src="red_traffic_light.png" width="150"    height="300" align=middle>
    <!-- <button onclick="setInterval(changelights, 1000)" >Start the timer</button> -->
    <script>
        var list = ["red_traffic_light.png", "red-amber-traffic-light.png","green_traffic_light.png", "amber-traffic-light.png"
                   ];

        var index = 0

        function changelights() {
            index = index + 1

            if (index == list.length) index = 0;
            var image = document.getElementById('change-light');
            image.src=list[index];
        }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just put the statement which is currently in the onclick under the changelights function, it would then start when the page loads

Comment: Additionally to what @Icepickle said: You also need to call `setInterval` in the `changelights` function, otherwise it will run only once.

Comment: @MarioWerner that would be the case with setTimeout, the setInterval simply keeps on calling the function until clearInterval is made

Comment: @Icepickle Ah ok, thanks for the clarification. Mixed that up. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just put `setInterval(changelights, 1000)` inside your script tag.

when browser run that line of code. it will start the timer.

```
<script>
    setInterval(changelights, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift responses, it is now acting as I wished.

Answer (score 0):

Call it when your document is ready:

With jQuery :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setInterval(changelights, 1000);
});
```

Pure javascript:

```
(function() {
   setInterval(changelights, 1000);
})();
```